# How to use custom Image in stepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I am using material-ui@next for my react app. I am struggling to find a way so that I can use and update `stepper` icon dynamically with `PNG` images.

Comment: I think you need an SVG image.

Comment: can you provide a sample

Comment: It says it in the [docs](https://material-ui-next.com/style/icons/).

Comment: I don't think there's anything regarding that in the docs and no such example too. I checked the source code too. There's no provision to add custom icons for steps. You can request a feature on their github repo issues though